# Postgresql view with json output

Tags: json, postgresql

I'd like to set up a postgres view which outputs its results as json.

The view should query a table called events:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW jsonview AS 
SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(t)) as events_as_json
FROM (SELECT * FROM events)t
```

and give results in a json. This works but I now, I'd like to specify the output of the view with something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM jsonview
WHERE events.year_begin = 1552;
```

But this produces an error due to non existing entry.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you want it all in a single row?

Comment: Yes, this is my purpose. I want the results in one nested json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create table-valued functions instead:

```
CREATE FUNCTION events_json()
RETURNS SETOF json
AS
$$
        SELECT  ARRAY_TO_JSON(ARRAY_AGG(T))
        FROM    events t
$$
LANGUAGE 'sql';

CREATE FUNCTION events_json(year INT)
RETURNS SETOF json
AS
$$
        SELECT  ARRAY_TO_JSON(ARRAY_AGG(T))
        FROM    events t
        WHERE   year_begin = $1;
$$
LANGUAGE 'sql';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a set

```
create or replace view jsonview as 
select row_to_json(t) as events_as_json
from events t
```

If you are going to search by a value then it is better to keep the column

```
create or replace view jsonview as 
select
    row_to_json(t) as events_as_json,
    year_begin
from events t
```

But what is the point of a JSON view? It sucks in all respects.

---

If you want an array of objects then the best is not to create a view and query it as

```
select json_agg(row_to_json(t)) as events_as_json
from events t
where year_begin = 1552
```

But if you really want to do it the very bad way and filter the array of objects from a view then create the view as:

```
create or replace view jsonview as
select json_agg(row_to_json(t)) as events_as_json
from events t
```

And filter the array

```
select json_agg(obj) as events_as_json
from (
    select json_array_elements(events_as_json) as obj
    from jsonview
) j 
where (obj ->> 'year_begin')::integer = 1552
```

Comment: The appreciation of the JSON view is to avoid JSON encoding within my Frameworks Controller (API). By letting Postgres create the JSON may be an speed optimisation (see: [Avoid ORM](http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/2014/05/27/avoid-rails-when-generating-json-responses-with-postgresql.html))

Comment: @kOssi Edited based on comments